# "Git push origin main" does not work for me

Tags: git, github, merge, push

Whenever I use `git push origin main` I get an error saying

`error: failed to push some refs to "repo link"`

to avoid this I have to use master instead of main to create a different branch altogether but when I visit github it already has main and master and if i rename master as main it again doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: What else does the error message tell you? non-fast-forward? There's hundreds of questions plus answers for that

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is: please include the _full_ error message (as text, NOT as image)

Comment: i have, "error: failed to push some refs to main" is the error message i get. I have given it as text.

Comment: No, that cannot be the full error message. I'm 99% certain that the error message has multiple lines.

Comment: it is my problem, in my system and I am telling you that it is one error message "error: failed to push some refs to main".

Comment: @knittl Where do you see an image in this question? I really dont see how you were 99% sure. Ig it would have been better had I given a picture so you'd know that it actually was the message that I received.

Comment: I don't see an image, and neither do I see the _full_ error message. I asked to include the _full_ error message as text (and not as image).

Comment: You would not see an image because i never put one there, also this was the full error message I am sure of that because I have seen it.

Comment: No, this is definitely not the full error message and it is incomplete. It is not even a full sentence and the error message of Git that starts with this phrase is several lines long: it includes the remote repository address (or alias) and the refs that failed to push. (I never claimed there was an image in the question, I only pointed out that the full error message shoudl be added as text)

Comment: @knittl Hey, just to prove my point I replicated the whole process and I guess I did omit some part of the full error message, sorry for that. I have now also added that as a picture, so you can see the whole error. I also gave an answer to solve it below.

Comment: Remember when I asked you to post the full error message as text and _not as picture_ (several times even)? Yet, you upload a picture? Did you read hint lines that Git provided, informing you about your local branch name? Additionally, every prompt line clearly shows `master` as the current branch name

Comment: well read the question i have provided both text and image, and actually the solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error I got when I started to learn git, the cause of this error is when you add a remote origin to a git repository, git on the system puts it on `master` branch but github has moved from `master` to `main` ([here](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-GitHub-renamed-its-master-branch-to-main))

To solve this issue:

1. Use `git checkout -b main`  to switch to main branch
2. Use `git pull origin main` to pull the main branch, add proper flags if you want to merge or rebase the branches
3. Now you can use `git push origin main` to push your work to the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

> when I visit github it already has `main` and `master`

If you want you local `main` branch to completely replace the remote GitHub one (and remove `master`), you would need:

```
git push --force origin main
git push --delete origin master
```

Comment: I really don't remember how the issue got resolved. Tho this wasn't what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @VaibhavSinghChandel No problem. Let use know if you get the same error again.